# Python notation question: string modulus?

Tags: javascript, python, string, dictionary, modulo

I've come across a snippet of Python code that looks like this:

```
code = 'foo' % bar
```

...where `foo` is a string of JavaScript code that's being used in a callback, and `bar` is a dictionary.

Can someone explain what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is beeing formatted using [the old %-formatting style](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting).

The string likely contains sequences like `%(foo)s` that are being replaced by the dictionary. An example would be:

```py
text = "Hello %(adjective)s World" % {"adjective": "beautiful"}
```

This would result in `Hello beautiful World`.

The text inside the parentheses denotes the keyword and the `s` after that denotes that it is a string. An alternative would be `d` for integers.

However using this method is not recommended anymore since [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) and the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) method provide better functionality.

Read more [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).